# Reading JSON data and display on GUI in Angular

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7, angular8

I am working in a angular application and I am trying to read data from my Json file and display it on GUI. I am successful in reading data from json file and I can see my object with data in console of my GUI. But I am not getting how to display required data on GUI.

My service class is as  follows:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'; 
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class RecipeService {

 // constructor() { }

 constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  this.getJSON().subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
  });
}

public getJSON(): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.get("./assets/locale/en.json");
}
}
```

My component code is as follows::

```
export class ReservationDetailsComponent implements OnInit {

 // lang$: Observable<string>;

  constructor(private reservationService:ServiceService) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.reservationService.getJSON().subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
  });
  }
```

My en.json is as follows:

```
{
    "SCREENS": {
        "HOME": {
            "TITLE": "Home Screen works"
        },        
        "DETAILS": {
            "TITLE": "Recipe Details works!"
        }
   }
}
```

In console  of my application I can see en.json data as object but I want to  display Recipe details on screen which I am unable to do so. Please help me to display it.

In my html file , My code is as follows:

```
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="title">
    {{ 'SCREENS.DETAILS.TITLE' | translate }} 
  </h1>
</div>
<p>recipe details screen</p>
```

I can see text in paragraph tag on  screen and I tried to fetch data on screeen something like this but it is not working.

I can see every time

```
<app-header></app-header>
<h1 style="text-align: center;">
   {{ 'SCREENS.HOME.TITLE' | translate }} 
</h1>
```

from app.component.html is displayed even I am using recipe url.

Answer (score 1):

I tried reproduce your code

HTML

```
  <div class="container">
  <h1 class="title">
    {{ data.SCREENS.HOME.TITLE }} 
  </h1>
</div>
<p> {{ data.SCREENS.DETAILS.TITLE }} </p>
```

TS

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.config.getData()
      .subscribe((data: any) => {
        this.data = data;
      });
  }
```

JSON service

```
@Injectable()
export class ConfigService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  getData() {
    return this.http.get('/assets/config.json');
  }
}
```

Demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/display-json-file?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: why you have made settings.service
?

Comment: that is my service for other purpose

Comment: code is running successfully but in GUI i am able to see only "home screen works" but with it I want "recipe details work" which is still not visible

Comment: do you want to invisible recipe details work if it show home screen works?

Comment: I cannot see your update. Well I updated question too for your understanding

Comment: in provider seciton you updated both service? Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you forgot to save the results of your query in an attribute of your class ReservationDetailsComponent.
So, try this:

```
export class ReservationDetailsComponent implements OnInit {

 private json;

  constructor(private reservationService:ServiceService) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.updateJson();
  }
  updateJson(){
        this.config.getData()
      .subscribe((data: any) => {
        this.json= data;
      });
  }
}
```

And in your html file, replace

```
<h1 class="title">
    {{ 'SCREENS.DETAILS.TITLE' | translate }} 
  </h1>
```

by :

```
<h1 class="title">
    {{ json.SCREENS.DETAILS.TITLE }} 
  </h1>
```

I think it should work.